# How to display image using canvas for all sizes

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm doing app which display one image within the canvas. It's working well in one device, but if I run same app in another devices the image is not displaying correctly, because in this `onDraw` I did not mention *imageview* width or height,so any one can u suggest me how to give width and hight to that *imageview* in side `onDraw` method.

My code is:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint painto = new Paint();
    painto.setAntiAlias(true);
    painto.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.magnata));
    painto.setStrokeWidth(3);
    painto.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int leftx2 = (int) (10 * (screenWidth / 1024));
    int topy1 = (int) (10 * (screenHeight / 600));

    Bitmap kangoo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.kangoo);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(kangoo, leftx2, topy1, painto);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set the width and height by using the onSizeChange().This can give you the changing width and height

```
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
         newwidth=w;
                 newheight=h;
    }
```

Comment: ok.but my code i am using kangoo image in this i didnt mention any hight and width previously .so if give  inside onsizechange() new width and hight also no use right?

Comment: Try using newwidth and newheight instead of screenWidth and screenHeight

Comment: yes. that screenwidth and screenhight are in wich  device i can run that device hight and width

Comment: ok,u first override the onSizeChange(), as I have shown above then use the newWidth and newheight in place of  screenwidth and screenhight in ur code

Comment: ok.here newwidth and newhight are intger varibles or float variables

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19580/discussion-between-user1105975-and-abhilash)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
@Override  
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
             newwidth=w;
                     newheight=h;
        }
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint painto = new Paint();
        painto.setAntiAlias(true);
        painto.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.magnata));
        painto.setStrokeWidth(3);
        painto.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int leftx2 = (int) (10 * (newwidth / 1024));
        int topy1 = (int) (10 * (newheight / 600));

        Bitmap kangoo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.kangoo);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(kangoo, leftx2, topy1, painto);
    }
```

Comment: is any another way is there to give imageview hight and width.

Comment: are u using getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight() to get the screenwidth and screenHeight ?

Comment: DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
          screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels; i treid usiing display metrics

Comment: You said u were using 4 images, So u can have 4 image views and 4 displayMetrics  for them

Comment: i have to display 4 imageviews.but displaymetrics is same

Comment: no sir i did'nt use imageview directly i give background to canvas

Comment: int widtho=(int)(202*(screenWidth/1024));
             int highto=(int)(213*(screenHeight/600));
             bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
               R.drawable.circles1_4);
             bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, widtho, highto, true);  finally i tried using scaledbitmap i got it.thanks